# Intersection graphs for "conflicting" directed paths in trees

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected tree and a set of directed paths in this tree (or equivalently, ordered $s$–$t$ pairs), we construct a graph with the paths as vertices and an edge between two paths if they traverse an edge of the tree in opposite directions. Is anything known about the resulting graphs? I found some similar settings, but none that exactly matches. Is this class equivalent to a known one, or does it have interesting characterizations or properties? The only thing I could find is that these graphs cannot have a $K_4$ as subgraph.

Answer (score 1):

This may count only as a "similar setting," but Martin Golumbic has studied what he
calls the *edge intersection graph* of a tree $T$, which has a node for each path
in $T$, and an arc between two nodes if their paths share at least one edge.
So his paths are not directed. He and coauthors have established a number of structural,
coloring, and complexity properties
of these "*EPT*" graphs, under various assumptions (e.g., on vertex degrees).
Here are three references:

- M.C. Golumbic, R.E. Jamison, Edge and vertex intersection of paths in a tree, *Discrete Mathematics* 
  55 (1985), 151-159. ([Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X85900433))
- Golumbic, Lipshteyn, and Stern, "Representing Edge Intersection Graphs of 
  Paths on Degree 4 Trees," *Discrete Mathematics*, 2008.
  ([DeepDyve link](http://www.deepdyve.com/lp/elsevier/representing-edge-intersection-graphs-of-paths-on-degree-4-trees-0Hf1tVf1z8)).
- Golumbic, Lipshteyn, and Stern,
  "The k-edge intersection graphs of paths in a tree,"
  *Discrete Applied Mathematics*,
  Volume 156, Issue 4, 2008. ([Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07003101))